# Entire Function with Finite Order and the Growth of its Coefficients. [Stein, Chapter 5, Problem 4 (b)]

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, entire-functions

This post is about part (b) of Stein Complex Analysis, Chapter 5, Problem 4. Part (a) has been asked and solved here: [Problem on entire function of finite order [Stein, Chapter 5, Problem 4]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3911804/problem-on-entire-function-of-finite-order-stein-chapter-5-problem-4/3911914?noredirect=1#3911914) (Conard gave a fantastic solution by not following Stein's instruction, but if you want to know how to do it following Stein's hint, I think the communication in comment would be enough.)

Part (b) is stated as follows:

> Let $F(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{n}$ be an entire function of finite order. If $$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}|a_{n}|^{\frac{1}{n}}n^{\frac{1}{\rho}}<\infty,$$ then $|F(z)|\leq A_{\epsilon}e^{a_{\epsilon}|z|^{\rho+\epsilon}}$, for every $\epsilon>0$

I think I have solved this but I cannot get the exact bound. The following is my proof

---

Let $r>0$. Suppose $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}|a_{n}|^{\frac{1}{n}}n^{\frac{1}{\rho}}=M<\infty$ and let $\epsilon>0$. Then, by definition there exists $N>0$ such that $|a_{n}|^{\frac{1}{n}}n^{\frac{1}{\rho}}<M+\epsilon,$ and thus $|a_{n}|<\frac{(M+\epsilon)^{n}}{n^{\frac{n}{\rho}}}.$

It implies that
$$|F(z)|\leq\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_{n}|\cdot |z|^{n}\leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(M+\epsilon)^{n}\cdot|z|^{n}}{n^{\frac{n}{\rho}}},$$ where the last inequality was obtained since only finitely number of $|a_{n}|^{\frac{1}{n}}n^{\frac{1}{\rho}}$ are greater than $M+\epsilon$, so it does not affect the bound on the whole infinite series.

We denote $C_{\epsilon}:=M+\epsilon$. It is well known that $n^{n}\geq n!$, and thus $$|F(z)|\leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(M+\epsilon)^{n}\cdot |z|^{n}}{n^{\frac{n}{\rho}}}\leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{C_{\epsilon}^{n}\cdot|z|^{n}}{(n!)^{\frac{1}{\rho}}}.$$

Recall an entire function has an order of growth $\leq \rho$ if $|f(z)|\leq Ae^{B|z|^{\rho}}$, and its order $\rho_{0}$ is the $\inf$ over all such $\rho$.

By Stein, Chapter 5, Problem 3, we know that $\sum\frac{z^{n}}{(n!)^{\alpha}}$ is an entire function of order $\frac{1}{\alpha}$, and thus we have $$\sum\frac{z^{n}}{(n!)^{\alpha}}\leq \Bigg|\sum\frac{z^{n}}{(n!)^{\alpha}}\Bigg|\leq Ae^{B|z|^{\rho}}=Ae^{B^{|z|^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}}}.$$

It means that in our case ($\alpha=\frac{1}{\rho}$), $$|F(z)|\leq  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{C_{\epsilon}^{n}\cdot |z|^{n}}{(n!)^{\frac{1}{\rho}}}\leq \Bigg|\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(C_{\epsilon}\cdot |z|)^{n}}{(n!)^{\frac{1}{\rho}}}\Bigg|\leq Ae^{B|C_{\epsilon}z|^{\rho}}\leq Ae^{B|C_{\epsilon}|^{\rho}\cdot |z|^{\rho+\epsilon}}.$$

---

So my question is the following:

1. Why in the statement of problem $A$ also depends on $\epsilon$?
2. I think Stein made some vague notation here, by $a_{\epsilon}$, did he mean the $a_{n}$ in the power series? If so, how could I include it?  If not, then I will just $a_{\epsilon}:=B|C_{\epsilon}|^{\rho}$, is this okay?

Have I done something wrong in my argument so that I cannot let $A$ depend on $\epsilon$?

Thank you for helping me!!!

Comment: $A_{\epsilon}, a_{\epsilon}$ are not that important (by increasing $A_{\epsilon}$ one can make $a_{\epsilon}$ whatever positive number you want eg $1$ by using the inequality at $\epsilon/2$) and $A_{\epsilon}$ just reflects the maximum of $|f|$ on some finite ball; however there is an issue with your proof, namely that order $1/\alpha$ doesn't imply the inequality you claim $\sum\frac{z^{n}}{(n!)^{\alpha}}\leq \Bigg|\sum\frac{z^{n}}{(n!)^{\alpha}}\Bigg|\leq Ae^{B|z|^{\rho}}=Ae^{B^{|z|^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}}}$ but only with an $\epsilon$ extra in the power

Comment: yes - where $A, B$, of course, depend on $\epsilon$ but as noted said dependence is really unimportant;

Comment: @Conrad Thanks for the comment  on $A_{\epsilon}$ and $a_{\epsilon}$, I will just leave like what I wrote above. For the second comment, so $\frac{1}{\alpha}$ is the infinitum of all $\rho$ such that $$\Bigg|\sum \dfrac{z^{n}}{(n!)^{\alpha}}\Bigg|\leq Ae^{B|z|^{\rho}},$$ so

Comment: yes - but it may happen that the inequality doesn't hold for $1/\alpha$ itself (think of $1/\Gamma$ or even $(s-1)\zeta(s)$ which are both entire functions of order $1$ but there is no $A,B$ st $|(s-1)\zeta(s)|\le Ae^{B|s|}$, only $|(s-1)\zeta(s)| \le A_{\epsilon}e^{|s|^{1+\epsilon}}$

Comment: @Conrad okay I get it. Yes, sorry for keeping editing my comment. I want to make the question clear. Yeah, so $\leq Ae^{B|z|^{\frac{1}{\alpha}+\epsilon}}$. Thank you!

Comment: @Conrad By the way, if you want, free feel to post a casual answer so that I can accept and vote :) I believe directly only moving comment to the answer will be great enough :)